# Additional space in the LaTeX output

Tags: spacing, floats

I have a question: In my LaTeX file I have this kind of code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.475\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/1}
    \caption{Caption1.}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.475\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/2}
    \caption{Caption2.}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption main.}
\label{fig:12}
\end{figure}
\newline
\indent
Normal Text
```

In the output file, "Normal Text" like starts with the indent in a new line as intended on a previous page to the one containing the `fig:12` which is absolutely ok, but then the rest of the text is separated from the `fig:12` by a huge space which I have no idea where it comes from. Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: The `figure` environment is a floating environment.  The `\newline` does nothing useful.  A blank line should have the result you want, and `\indent` shouldn't be needed.  Exactly what is happening depends on what precedes the figure, and you haven't shown that.  It would be best if you could provide a small compilable example (beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that demonstrates the problem.  That will give potential helpers something to experiment with.

Comment: `\indent` never does anything useful in a latex document, and as Barbara says, `\newline` after a figure is wrong as the figure will float but the `\newline` will apply in that place (and most likely give an error).

Comment: BTW: better is to use a label like `\label{fig:<name-of-figure>}`. The advantages are (1) that you can better remember the name of the figure, you can also have a label for the section with same name `\label{sec:<name-of-figure>}` (different in leading `sec:` or `tab:` or `fig:`). And (2) if you change the order of figures etc you will have a lot of trouble to locate the correct figure ...

Comment: Thank you everyone, I'll try to provide a compilable example. The only thing about the newline which actually I don't understand, I used to put a space (with enter) and it did have the same effect as newline but at some point in the document the space increased to two spaces. I didn't put any command changes and whatnot so I replaced the enters with newline commands